# Implementations of prefix lookup tables

Tags: python, performance, binary-search, lookup

I've got a fairly performance sensitive need for fast prefix lookup, and I've built two different implementations trying to optimize for my use case.  The first is built off a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) implementation, and the second uses binary search.  Testing them both, the Trie provides faster lookup, and much faster insertion, but dramatically slower initialization, which is my primary concern.

I'm looking for ways to optimize either of these tools, and would very much appreciate help improving initialization time of the Trie, or search/insert time of the binary search.

I know it's a fair bit of code, I [posted it on gist](https://gist.github.com/2981061) if people find that more convenient.

**error.py** Shared exceptions

```
class UnknownPrefix(Exception):
    '''Raised if a given prefix does not map to any items'''
    def __init__(self,prefix,*args):
        Exception.__init__(self,*args)
        self.prefix = prefix

class AmbiguousPrefix(Exception):
    '''Raised if a given prefix maps to multiple items'''
    def __init__(self,prefix,choices,*args):
        Exception.__init__(self,*args)
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.choices = choices
```

**tprefix.py** Trie Prefix Implementation

```
import error;

class Prefix:
    '''
    A trie datastructure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) which enables
    fast data retrieval by prefix.

    Note that for more reasonable lookup, the trie only searches in lower
    case.  This means there can be colliding strings such as 'prefix' vs 'Prefix'.
    In this case, more recent inserts override older ones. 
    '''

    def __init__(self,ls=[]):
        self._root = _Node(None,None,True)
        self._aliases = {}
        for i in ls:
            self._root.add(i.lower(),i)

    def __getitem__(self, prefix):
        '''Return the item with the given prefix.

        If more than one item matches the prefix an AmbiguousPrefix exception
        will be raised, unless the prefix is the entire ID of one task.

        If no items match the prefix an UnknownPrefix exception will be raised.

        If an item exactly matches the prefix, it will be returned even if
        there exist other (longer) items which match the prefix
        '''
        matched = self._root[prefix.lower()]
        if (matched is None or
            (matched.result is None and len(matched.children) == 0) or
            # this is needed because prefix will return if prefix
            # is longer than necessary, and the necessary part
            # matches, but the extra text does not
            (matched.key is not None and not matched.key.startswith(prefix.lower()))):
            raise error.UnknownPrefix(prefix)
        if matched.result is not None:
            if matched.result in self._aliases:
                return self._aliases[matched.result]
            else: return matched.result
        else:
            raise error.AmbiguousPrefix(prefix,iter(matched))

    def prefix(self,item):
        '''Return the unique prefix of the given item, or None if not found'''
        return self._root.prefix(item.lower())

    def pref_str(self,pref,short=False):
        '''returns the item with a colon indicating the shortest unique prefix'''
        item = self[pref]
        pref = self.prefix(item)
        tail = item[len(pref):]
        return item[:len(pref)]+':'+(tail[:4]+('...' if len(tail) > 4 else '') if short else tail)

    def add(self,item):
        '''Add an item to the data structure'''
        self._root.add(item.lower(),item,0)

    def alias(self,alias,item):
        '''Add an item to the trie which maps to another item'''
        self._aliases[alias] = self[item]
        self.add(alias)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._root)

class _Node:
    '''Represents a node in the Trie.  It contains either
    an exact match, a set of children, or both
    '''

    def __init__(self, key, item, final=False):
        '''Constructs a new node which contains an item'''
        self.final = final
        self.key = key
        self.result = item
        self.children = {}

    def _tree(self):
        '''Returns a tree structure representing the trie.  Useful for debugging'''
        return "( %s%s, { %s } )" % (self.result, '*' if self.final else '',
                                   ', '.join(["%s: %s" % (k,v._tree()) for (k,v) in self.children.items()]))

    def add(self,key,item,depth=0):
        '''Adds an item at this node or deeper.  Depth indicates
        which index is being used for comparison'''
        # the correct node has been found, replace result with new value
        if self.key is not None and key == self.key:
            self.result = item #this would override an old value
            return

        # this is currently a leaf node, move the leave one down
        if self.result is not None and not self.final:
            if self.key == None: print(self.key,self.result,key,item)
            key_letter = self.key[depth]
            self.children[key_letter] = _Node(self.key,self.result,len(self.key)==depth+1)
            self.key = None
            self.result = None

        if len(item) == depth:
            self.key = key
            self.result = item #this could override an old value
            self.final = True
            return

        letter = key[depth]
        if letter in self.children:
            child = self.children[letter]
            child.add(key,item,depth+1)
        else:
            self.children[letter] = _Node(key,item,len(key) == depth+1)

    def __getitem__(self,prefix):
        '''Given a prefix, returns the node that matches
        This will either have a result, or if not the prefix
        was ambiguous.  If None is returned, there was no
        such prefix'''
        if len(prefix) == 0 or len(self.children) == 0:
            return self
        letter = prefix[0]
        if letter in self.children:
            return self.children[letter][prefix[1:]]
        else: return None

    def prefix(self,item):
        '''Given an item (or a prefix) finds the shortest
        prefix necessary to reach the given item.
        None if item does not exist.'''
        if len(item) == 0 or len(self.children) == 0:
            return ''
        letter = item[0]
        if letter in self.children:
            child = self.children[letter].prefix(item[1:])
            if child is not None:
                return letter + child 
        return None

    def __iter__(self):
        '''Yields items in and below this node'''
        if self.result:
            yield self.result
        for k in sorted(self.children.keys()):
            for res in self.children[k]:
                yield res
```

**bprefix.py** Binary Search Prefix Implementation

```
import bisect
import error;

class Prefix:
    '''
    A prefix data structure built on a sorted list, which uses binary search.

    Note that for more reasonable lookup, it only searches in lower
    case.  This means there can be colliding strings such as 'prefix' vs 'Prefix'.
    In this case, more recent inserts override older ones.
    '''
    def __init__(self, ls=[], presorted=False):
        self._aliases = {}
        self._list = ls if presorted else sorted(ls)
        self._keys = [s.lower() for s in self._list]

    # Note that since we usually use these methods together, it's wasteful to
    # Compute prefix.lower() for both - as such, these methods assume prefix
    # is already lower case.
    def _getindex(self, prefix):
        return bisect.bisect_left(self._keys, prefix)
    def _getnextindex(self, prefix):
        # http://stackoverflow.com/a/7381253/113632
        lo, hi = 0, len(self._keys)
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (lo+hi)//2
            if prefix < self._keys[mid] and not self._keys[mid].startswith(prefix): hi = mid
            else: lo = mid+1
        return lo

    def __getitem__(self, prefix):
        '''Return the item with the given prefix.

        If more than one item matches the prefix an AmbiguousPrefix exception
        will be raised, unless the prefix is the entire ID of one task.

        If no items match the prefix an UnknownPrefix exception will be raised.

        If an item exactly matches the prefix, it will be returned even if
        there exist other (longer) items which match the prefix
        '''
        pre = prefix.lower()
        ret = self._list[self._getindex(pre):self._getnextindex(pre)]
        if ret:
            if len(ret) == 1 or ret[0].lower() == pre:
                return ret[0]
            raise error.AmbiguousPrefix(prefix,ret)
        raise error.UnknownPrefix(prefix)

    def prefix(self, item):
        '''Return the unique prefix of the given item, or None if not found'''
        ln = len(self._keys)
        item = item.lower()
        index = self._getindex(item)
        if index >= ln:
            return None
        match = self._keys[index]
        if not match.startswith(item):
            return None

        siblings = []
        if index > 0:
            siblings.append(self._keys[index-1])
        if index < ln-1:
            siblings.append(self._keys[index+1])

        if not siblings: #list contains only item
            return match[0]

        return self._uniqueprefix(match,siblings)

    def _uniqueprefix(self,match,others):
        '''Returns the unique prefix of match, against the set of others'''
        ret = []
        #print("START:",match,others)
        while match:
            others = [s[1:] for s in others if s and s[0] == match[0]]
            ret.append(match[0])
            match = match[1:]
            #print("WHILE:",match,others,''.join(ret))
            if not others:
                return ''.join(ret)
        return None

    def add(self,item):
        '''Add an item to the data structure.

        This uses list.insert() which is O(n) - for many insertions,
        it may be dramatically faster to simply build a new Prefix entirely.'''
        lower = item.lower()
        index = self._getindex(lower)
        # If overwriting same key
        if index < len(self._keys) and self._keys[index] == lower:
            self._list[index] = item
        else:
            self._keys.insert(index,lower)
            self._list.insert(index,item)

    def alias(self,alias,item):
        '''Add an item to the trie which maps to another item'''
        self._aliases[alias] = self[item]
        self.add(alias)

    def pref_str(self,pref,short=False):
        '''returns the item with a colon indicating the shortest unique prefix'''
        item = self[pref]
        pref = self.prefix(item)
        tail = item[len(pref):]
        return item[:len(pref)]+':'+(tail[:4]+('...' if len(tail) > 4 else '') if short else tail)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._list)
```

**test.py** Series of testing / timing functions

```
import hashlib,time
import bprefix,tprefix

def timed(f):
    def func(*args):
        start = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        took = time.time() - start
        print("%s took %f" % (f.__name__,took))
        return ret
    return func

def get_generator(top=250000,static="Static_String"):
    return (hashlib.sha1((static+str(i)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() for i in range(top))


@timed
def build_from_list(cls):
    return cls(get_generator())

@timed
def build_from_adds(cls):
    pref = cls()
    for s in get_generator(10000):
        pref.add(s)
    return pref

@timed
def add_to(obj):
    for s in get_generator(10000,"Different_String"):
        obj.add(s)

@timed
def get(obj,loops=10000):
    for _ in range(loops):
        obj['000188']
        obj['1971e']
        obj['336f7']
        obj['4d120']
        obj['66ada']
        obj['80736']
        obj['99cb0']
        obj['b38f3']
        obj['ccfd9e8']
        obj['e61df']

@timed
def prefix(obj,loops=10000):
    for _ in range(loops):
        obj.prefix('00018855b442bfba15fae6949982ef63d9eba1c9')
        obj.prefix('1971e17df8ee57f0dcceccc869db454b7c6b7a54')
        obj.prefix('336f7b09c7c0c933b1f26ca09a84585818046e6b')
        obj.prefix('4d1209fadf843f65bd2beee37db552134a930395')
        obj.prefix('66adaf0cb611d71554153631611f7904781addef')
        obj.prefix('80736f454201d96c4c795bb5e21778550a9cbef0')
        obj.prefix('99cb006fd81cb84cfbae834ed7b7f977c29af249')
        obj.prefix('b38f3561591650708fce739536ac504f86fecdf5')
        obj.prefix('ccfd9e8211621666c55f911d1ff3f13ab93f696e')
        obj.prefix('e61df82a0c2f59394eb9bd752e93b9c011df5be2')

@timed
def iter(obj):
    for s in obj:
        len(s)

def run_tests(cls):
    pref = build_from_list(cls)
    build_from_adds(cls)
    add_to(pref)
    get(pref)
    prefix(pref)
    iter(pref)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("TRIE STRUCTURE")
    run_tests(tprefix.Prefix)
    print("BINARY SEARCH STRUCTURE")
    run_tests(bprefix.Prefix)
```

**Output of test.py**

> ```
> TRIE STRUCTURE
> build_from_list took 5.736888
> build_from_adds took 0.189277
> add_to took 0.193403
> get took 1.103995
> prefix took 1.000542
> iter took 1.205267
> BINARY SEARCH STRUCTURE
> build_from_list took 1.382333
> build_from_adds took 0.123948
> add_to took 2.092292
> get took 2.206803
> prefix took 2.141418
> iter took 0.071968
> ```

Comment: Do you think about pure C character trie implementation, wrapped into python extension like:https://github.com/buriy/python-chartrie

Comment: Your errors could probably just be KeyError and ValueError. Avoid introducing new types unless they really do need special handling.

Comment: @cat_baxter - I do, but C is outside my expertise.  I'll see if I can't get your link to work though, thanks.

Comment: @Daenyth - Hmm, I thought of them both as types of KeyErrors - you think Ambiguous should be a ValueError?  They do provide additional information, access to the input and the error, and I use that additional information, does that count as special handling?  It would make sense I think for them to inherit from Key/ValueError, rather than Exception.

Comment: Is there a case where you'd handle your error differently than a KeyError? Or ValueError for invalid (duplicate) input? If the only thing that's different is the name of the exception, just put that information in the error message and use a builtin type - it makes your tools easier to use.

Comment: @Daenyth well my program uses prefix lookups for several different structures (IDs, usernames, commands, etc.) and the behavior is different depending on the use case, so it's quite helpful for me to access the passed prefix and list of choices directly.

Comment: @cat_baxter With the help of the developer, I gave the C implementation you linked to a try, but unfortunately it's not built to enable longest prefix match.

Comment: You may also try http://pypi.python.org/pypi/datrie/ which is an another fast trie implementation with many features.

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance I would suggest  [BioPython Library](http://biopython.org) It has nice and very fast implementation of trie with prefix search, serialization, etc.

It's a small example using word file (~179.000 words):

```
from Bio import trie
import StringIO
import time

words = open('twl06.txt').read().split()

stime = time.time()
t = trie.trie()
for word in words:
    t[word] = 1
print "Building time (s)", time.time()-stime

stime = time.time()
print t.with_prefix("HELLO")
print "Searching time (s)", time.time()-stime

stime = time.time()
f = open('trie.bin','wb')
trie.save(f, t)
f.close()
print "Serialization time time (s)", time.time()-stime

stime = time.time()
f = open('trie.bin','rb')
t1 = trie.load(f)
f.close()
print "Deserialization time time (s)", time.time()-stime

print t1.with_prefix("HELLO")
```

And the output:

```
d:\python27\python test.py
Building time (s) 0.18799996376
['HELLO', 'HELLOED', 'HELLOES', 'HELLOING', 'HELLOS']
Searching time (s) 0.0
Serialization time time (s) 0.953000068665
Deserialization time time (s) 0.766000032425
['HELLO', 'HELLOED', 'HELLOES', 'HELLOING', 'HELLOS']
```